# Is it possible to hide all theme related packages from Cydia?

Tags: cydia

Cydia is spammed by too many skinning tweaks and it is real hard to browse for more interesting applications.

Do you know a way to make Cydia hide the theme-related packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cydia > Sections > Edit

Turn the toggle to "Off" next to the "Theme" sections.

Comment: Thanks, that's cool, I can filter the "noise" this way and focus on more interesting things.

Comment: Incorrect. Themes still show in search results even when you turn all Theme sections off.